# Downloading different images sizes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, preload

I'm writing a website that downloads a gallery of images from an S3 bucket. The problem is that the images uploaded to the bucket can be very large, which can lead to poor performance in the gallery. I am currently using simple Javascript to go through my array of S3 URLs and change the slideshow image's source every few seconds. I am also preloading the images sequentially in order to cache them and improve performance:

```
function preload(imageArray, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    if (imageArray && imageArray.length > index) {
        var img = new Image ();
        img.onload = function() {
            console.log("Preloaded: ", img.src)
            preload(imageArray, index + 1);
        }
        img.src = imageArray[index];
    }
}
```

What is the best practice for limiting the file size of the images I download from my S3 bucket? Would I do this in preloading, or would I set a property of the gallery's `img` element?

Comment: You could use a JS lazy loading library to improve speed and through that either download a really low quality image as a placeholder or just use a placeholder on initial load, and then the library will help replace the placeholder one by one either on a particular event or as they load

Comment: Would there be a way to compress the images client side though? I don't want the slideshow to switch between low quality thumbnails and high resolution images.

Comment: Your images are on the server, in which case you need to have such a script in the server which you can call through the API which will return your resized/compressed image. 
You cannot just simply resize it in your in your script running in the browser cause this will not improve the performance as you will have to download the full size image in order to resize it. See the problem. Therefor the lazyloading option would be the best option unless you have script which does resize the image prior to being uploaded to your AWS bucket, or on server which can be called and generate them on the fly